# White parts of video glitches

Tags: video

[image]

Fullscreen video played from youtube, also happens in VLC

1. The white areas of the video glitches
2. Doesn't show up in a screenshot
3. Goes away when you replay the video

System specifications- MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015), OS X Yosemite.

Any ideas? Google wasn't helpful

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I use F.lux to make the screen more orange. Disabling it makes the glitches go away.